# Cannot restore resized icons in Home Folder

Tags: icons

I resized the icons in the Home folder using Home/Edit/Preferences/Icon View Defaults/Default Zoom Level 66%. This worked fine but when I wanted to put them back to 100% it wont work. They are stuck at 66%.
Similarly in Home/Documents I made the Default Zoom Level 150%. The changed and are now stuck at 150%.
I can change into list mode and back again OK but the icons are stuck at the selected sizes. How do I recover from this?

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl+ to zoom in and ctrl- to zoom out.

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever, this has fixed the problem. Problem solved